# Laravel 5.2 Submitting Form Data

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am submitting form to /add route BUT when i click on submit button it gives this error
Using : Larvel 5

> { SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate
>   entry '$name' for key 'name' (SQL: insert into `projects` (`id`,
>   `name`, `money`, `anything`) values (, $name, 20, asfsf)) }

**FORM :**

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => 'add')) !!}
  {!! Form::text('name', 'example@gmail.com') !!}
  {!! Form::submit('Click Me!')!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**Routes.php**

```
Route::post('add', function () {
   $test = Input::get('name');
   echo $test;
});
```

**DB Snap:**
[image]

PS: I want to echo the input field value but it gives the above mentioned error.

Comment: Can you share your migration file or table schema for `projects`?

Comment: Why I don't see any DB related code in `add` route?

Comment: Probably, you are typing `'$name'` somewhere, where you should type just `$name`.

Comment: @JeffLambert edited please check

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin I want to check first if it is working for just echo or not , then I will add DB related code . And even I did but not working.
DB::table('projects')->insert(array('name'=>'test','money'=>'30'));

Comment: I've just tested your code and it works fine. I can see `example@gmail.com` as output. I've created view and copy-pasted your form there. Also, I've copy-pasted your route. Works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're inserting nothing for the id. notice the blank space before the comma in `values (, $name, 20, asfsf)) }`.

If your id field is set to auto-increment (looks like it is) then remove `id` from your insert statement.

```
insert into projects (name, money, anything) values ($name, 20, 'asfsf')
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer however my problem was project folder.I was opening URL of another project and was editing in another project.